# Can two simple NFC tags communicate with each other?

Tags: tags, nfc

Can two NFC tags directly transfer data between each other or do I need an NFC reader to read/access them?

I mean, is it possible to stick two adhesive tags on top of each other and have one tag transfer data to the other tag without using a cellphone or NFC reader?

The tags look like this one:

[image]

Comment: Your typical cheap NFC tag isn't programmable, just a number. Let's ignore the technical details for a second. Take two numbers, say 5 and 6. How is the number 5 going to do anything with the number 6?? This question is really weird.

Answer (score 3):

No, they can't. There's no power supply in them. You need a reader that "activates" them.